# Prevent subdomain from redirecting to rootdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have created a new subdomain (sub.domain.com) but it keeps redirecting to the rootdomainname (domain.com). So I can't edit my website or login (Wordpress).

I first assumed the plugin WP fast cache was the problem:

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wp_woocommerce_session
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/username/domains/example.com/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

so I deactivated the plugin temporarily to change the htaccess file back to the basic file (to see if the plugin was the problem):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

but it still redirects to the root domainname.

I have tried to add the following code in the .htaccess file without success I am a beginner with .htaccess files so I might have add it to the file in the wrong way:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.co/%1/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.co/
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What can I do so the subdomain won't redirect to the root domain but just to the subdomain itself?

I have the simple ssl plugin installed as well but I have tried the same for this plugin (deactivating the plugin and used the last code in this message).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Empty your browser cache every time you change something. Redirects *are* cached.

If you only keep the base wordpress logic in your `.htaccess` file it shouldn't redirect to the base domain, unless this is the domain you defined in the wordpress config.

If that's the case, you need to manually edit the config in the database, or simply access the wordpress interface from the root domain, if it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your respons!

I have set the .htacces back to:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

There are no redirections added to the wp config.

Because I can't login in this subdomain (because it only redirects to the root domain) the database is still empty. I did upload the Wordpress files, wp-config and htaccess but I can't access and install Wordpress yet because of this redirection and so there is no database information yet.